# How to set up an HTTP server to support Git and Subversion dual-protocol, with the same base URL, like Github?

Tags: git, github, svn

Github-hosted code repos has been amazing to me for many years. Using the **same** base URL, like `https://github.com/chjfth/dailytools.git`, we can use it

- from git client, do `git clone`; and
- from svn client, do `svn checkout`.

[image: Github-hosted repo dual protocol support.]

[image: Use TortoiseSVN to browse git repo.]

**How does he do that? Is it a technique private to Github company, or is it available as an open-source software?**

If svn client checks-in some file to server side, the change appears immediately to `git fetch`, vice versa. All things happen realtime, like a breeze.

There must be some live protocol translator that runs on Github server farm that dynamically change svn protocol to Git backend storage.

I've read and tried Git's official guide about setting up [Smart HTTP facility](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) serving Git repos over Apache httpd 2.4.52. It works quite well.

Then how should I go one more step to achieve Subversion client support via the same Apache httpd instance? I Googled for this and it seems no person is talking about this, so I ask here at stackoverflow.com in hope to get some hint.

BTW: I have noticed [git-as-svn](https://github.com/git-as-svn/git-as-svn) and tried it as well. Good, it works after some configuration puzzle, and I think it meets 90% of my expectation to set up a svn/git dual-protocol server. Currently, one downside of git-as-svn is that svn client needs to use `svn://` scheme, instead of the unified `http://` scheme.